# Who to get/copy a specific word from a text file using bash?

Tags: bash, terminal

when I do this:

```
LINE=$(head -38 fine.txt | tail -1 | cut -f2)
```

I get the 38th line of the file, which is:

```
Xres  = 1098
```

but I only need to record 1098 as value for a variable.

I am training to read a text file and record values and use them as parameters later in my script.

Comment: what is whole content of the  line38?

Comment: What does `LINE=$(head -38 fine.txt | tail -1)` look like? What is `cut` used for? You could get what you want by tweaking the arguments of `cut` a bit.

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as accepted.  Until you do, this question will continue to show up as unresolved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `| awk '{print $3}'` to the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '38s/.*= *//p' fine.txt
```

By default, `sed` prints every input line. The `-n` option disables this behavior. `38` selects line number 38 and when this line is seen, the substitution replaces everything up to the last equals sign with nothing, and prints.

That's assuming the second field is the last field. If the input line is more complex than I have assumed, try the substitution `s/^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*= *//p`. If your `sed` does not recognize `\t` as a tab character, you'll need to supply literal tabs (you can enter one with the key sequence ctrl-v tab in some shells).

If the input file is large, you may want to refactor the `sed` script to quit after the 38th line.

Wrapping up, that gets us

```
LINE=$(sed -n '38!b;s/^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*= *//p;q' fine.txt)
```

However, this is becoming somewhat complex, to the point of hampering legibility and thus maintainability.  The same in Awk is more readable;

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR==38 { sub(/.*= */,"",$2); print $2; exit 0 }' fine.txt
```

More generally, you might want to split on tabs, then on spaces.  The following implements `cut -f2 | awk '{ print $3 }'` more precisely:

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR==38 { split($2,f); print f[3]; exit 0 }' fine.txt
```

The option `-F '\t'` sets tab as the input field separator.  The condition `NR==38` selects the 38th line, and `split($2,f)` splits the second tab-separated field on spaces into the array `f`.  Then we simply print the third element of `f`, and `exit`.